# Firmware ENC28J60: Transmit Length Check Error

Tags: c, driver, ethernet, firmware

I am working on writing my own firmware to control the ENC28J60 to add an extra ethernet port to an Odroid.

When I am writing my transmit packet firmware, the transmit status vector is giving me a Transmit Length Check Error. To my understanding the only field that is influencing this error is the type/length field. I am doing a test by trying to transmit "Hello World" as a result my type/length field contains 11 because "Hello World" is 11 bytes (10 letters + 1 space).

Any ideas how the type/length field is suppose to be calculated? That is the only thing I can think about that I might be doing wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's an `ENC28J60`? What platform are you running on? What hardware? What OS? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..